# No canoniza C14N una XML con una namespace raro

Tags: php, xml

Realicé este ejemplo:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan 12 2019 13:11:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

# nano test.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file= 'archivo.xml';
echo "\n## Prueba de Canonizado C14N()\n";

if( !file_exists($file) )
        echo "\nArchivo nomina.xml no existe...";
else {
        $xml= new DOMDocument( "1.0", "UTF-8" );
        $xml->formatOutput= true;
        $xml->loadXML(file_get_contents($file));
        $xmldata= $xml->C14N();
        echo "\nArchivo: ". $file;    
        echo "\n\nData C14N() [". md5($xmldata). "]:\n";
        print_r($xmldata);
}
echo "\n\nFin del programa...\n\n";
exit(0);
?>

# ./test.php
PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Relative namespace UR is invalid here : dian in /app/test.php on line 12
PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Internal error : checking for relative namespaces in /app/test.php on line 12
PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Internal error : processing docs children list in /app/test.php on line 12
```

El `archivo.xml` es un XML que tiene despues de estarle moviendo, logre funcionara C14N() pero desgraciadamente la entidad tributaria no me lo acepta asi :(, requiere a fuerza vayan los namespaces como el los pide.

El error que podemos ver se desata por que existen estas 2 declaraciones en la cabecera del XML:

```
<NominaIndividual xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual"
 xsi:schemaLocation="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual
 NominaIndividualElectronicaXSD.xsd" .....
```

Esa es la manera "normal" como lo pide y pues da error en la funcion C14N() de php :(....

Con la finalidad de hacerlo pasar por C14N(), lo modifique pero como mencione, no me lo acepta asi el webservice de gobierno:

```
<NominaIndividual xmlns="uri:dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual"
 xsi:schemaLocation="uri:dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual
 NominaIndividualElectronicaXSD.xsd" .....
```

Vaya, C14N() en PHP al agregarle el elemento `uri:` ya lo canoniza, pero si le retiro ese fragmento, bota el error:

> PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Relative namespace UR is invalid here :
> dian in /app/test.php on line 12 PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N():
> Internal error : checking for relative namespaces in /app/test.php on
> line 12 PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Internal error : processing
> docs children list in /app/test.php on line 12

¿Que podré hacer?

1. No puedo cambiar de version de PHP :(
2. Debo incluir los namespaces como los pide gobierno :(
3. Si los cambio agregando "uri:" me lo rechaza el Webservice de gobierno.

Saludos !

Comment: Si pudieras usar una versión más reciente, posiblemente no chocarías con ésto. De hecho, veo que hay [opciones publicadas](https://github.com/Stenfrank/soap-dian) para hacer esto mismo... habría que explorar si procesas el XML con oootra librería diferente que pueda hacer canonization sin ese lío para tu versión de PHP...

Comment: @Alfabravo sin duda comprendo que si no tuviera esa version de PHP forzada, podria resolverlo sin problema. Ya que en mi laptop tengo la version 8 y no tengo problema alguno :(

Pero me imagino que debe existir una forma de resolverlo en la version actual de PHP, no?

Comment: Prueba con esta [librería](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs). Tu problema pareciera estar en la versión de libxml que está en ese PHP...

Comment: @Alfabravo ijole, estamos hablando de un sistema robusto donde cambiar esa libreria de firmado digital, seria un caos enorme jajajaja... De hecho la libreria de firmado digital es creada por nosotros mismos, pero en especifico la funcion C14N() es una funcion que viene con PHP

Comment: Por eso te digo. El lío al canonizar es de libxml. Si quieres que no reviente, te tocaría no usar libxml (que ya sabemos que es la que viene con PHP). No se trata de todo el firmado, sólo del parseo de los XML. _No hay almuerzo gratis_, sobre todo si es algo con la DIAN ;)

Comment: @Marcos este es el XML de nomina a como lo generami plataforma con el "urn:" en el argumento de "xmlns" --> https://pastebin.com/tSxJJCW4

Comment: @moneyBox, ¿de donde sacaste el XML? Según [esta documentación](https://www.dian.gov.co/impuestos/factura-electronica/Documents/PPT-Piloto-documento-soporte-de-pago-de-nomina-electronica.pdf) (Pag 29) y [esta otra](https://www.dian.gov.co/normatividad/Normatividad/Resoluci%c3%b3n%20000013%20de%2011-02-2021.pdf) (Pag 9) te estan sobrando atributos. En [esta demo](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/19a05) tu error no se puede reproducir

Comment: @moneyBox te recomiendo entrar a este link https://www.dian.gov.co/impuestos/factura-electronica/Documents/Caja-de-Herramientas-Nomina-Electronica-V1-0.zip (contiene todo lo que necesitas)

Comment: @Marcos estoy consciente que hay 2 o 3 declarciones que no es necesario vayan, pero esas declaraciones extras no alteran el XML ya que son solo esquemas que en caso de usarse, ya se aplicarian. En este caso, estan extras, pero no hay problema con eso.

El problema es el archivo que estoy pasandole https://pastebin.com/tSxJJCW4, Lo extra~o es que en la ruta DEMO que me mandaste, no le tira error, entonces que podra ser? que podria indagar en mi instalacion de php ?

Comment: @moneyBox lo que te comentaba sobre atributos de mas, te lo señale porque según la documentación indica _"No inventar nuevos elementos"_ lo cual pareciera ser el caso. Con respecto que podría ser el problema, según pude leer por ahí, puede que _"libxml2"_ tenga algo que ver, pero realmente no lo se.

Comment: Hola @Marcos para no quedar con la duda, he eliminado las dos cabeceras adicionales en el XML de nomina dejando el nuevo que procese asi --> https://pastebin.com/hXM1Qzup 

Pero aun continua saliendo el error: NIE901, Rechazo: El documento debe poseer Todos los Namespace correspondientes a su estructura

Y asumo que es por que mando "urn:dian" en vezde "dian"... en la canbecera que ya mencione en el mensaje princial del post :'(

Comment: Sin duda creo que el tema va por libxml2

Comment: He verificado phpinfo() y me dice que la version de libxml que tengo es 2.9.1

Comment: hice pull a la imagen "webdevops/php-apache" y esta tiene un PHP 7.4, y curiosamente despues de levantar el contenedor docker y ejecutar el mismo codigo PHP, marca el mismo error. Esto sin duda alguna quiere decir que el problema es algo en la configuracion del PHP del contenedor que estoy corriendo.

Comment: Hice un contenedor aparte haciendo pull a una imagen raw de "ubuntu/apache2", levante, ingrese, instale PHP 7.4 y vuala... C14N ya no tira error.
Creo me va tocar hacer mi propia imagen y ponerla en el registry de docker :'(

Comment: Comprobado "php-fpm" tiene algo configurado que jode la canonizacion con C14N, pero su usas un php normalito, este no limita en nada a la canonicacion con C14N

Answer (score 1):

El problema viene dado porque las URN que usa la DIAN para algunos namespace en facturación electrónica no están normalizados como lo indica la [W3](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/URNsAndRegistries-50.html).

Al no estar normalizada la declaración del namespace, PHP (sobretodo en ambientes Linux) a través de la función C14N, genera un error indicando que no se puede canonizar el XML

```
PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Relative namespace UR is invalid here : dian
PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Internal error : checking for relative namespaces
PHP Warning:  DOMNode::C14N(): Internal error : processing docs children list
```

Para solucionar este error, que viene heredado de la librería LibXML2 que viene en PHP, lo que se debe hacer es normalizar esos namespaces que no se encuentren en cumplimiento de lo que dicta la W3. Por ejemplo, un caso de normalización normal es agragar la cadena "urn:" antes del URN original del namespace que tiene el problema. A continuación un ejemplo.

```
xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual" => xmlns="urn:dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual"
```

Para evitar que se dañe la firma de los documentos, ese reemplazo se debe hacer sólo para la canonización del documento con la función C14N, y posterior a esta canonización, restaurar el namespace a su estado original. Acá dejo el ejemplo que me ha funcionado y que ya está funcionando frente a las validaciones de la DIAN:

```php
function CanonizarXML($DocumentoXML){
    $Xml_norm = str_ireplace('"dian:', '"urn:dian:', $DocumentoXML);
    @!$doc->loadXML($Xml_norm, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE)
    if ($Xml_Canonizado = @$doc->C14N(true, false, null, null)) {
        $Xml_Canonizado = str_ireplace('"urn:dian:', '"dian:', $DocumentoXML);
        return $XmlCanonizado;
    }
}
```

Espero les sea de ayuda, ya que en nómina electrónica la DIAN restringió el tema de los namespace a partir de mediados de marzo de 2022, y es probable que empiecen a aplicar esas restricciones al resto de documentos electrónicos.

Comment: Lo que hice para solucionar y evitar hacer el `str_ireplace()` fue actualizar PHP a la version 7.4 sin soporte FPM y listo, solucionado !

Comment: curiosamente si colocas cualquier PHP del tipo "FPM", si o si, fallara en el canonizado. PEro si pruebas SIN FPM, no falla !